# function undef under release

Tags: erlang

I'm having trouble with a release package (created by `systools:make_tar`). When I run it with code from erlang installation (`/usr/local/lib/erlang/`), it runs perfectly. Only when I switch to code provided with my release package (`/some/other/dir`) it starts throwing up `undef` exceptions.

Here's what I know:

1. I'm running all this by executing `/some/other/dir/erts-5.8.1/bin/erl -sname test -boot /some/other/dir/releases/0.0.1/start`
2. Package was created successfully (code compiled/app/rel/sys.config included)
3. I'm changing `/some/other/dir/erts-5.8.1/bin/erl` to set path to my code (from `/usr/local/lib/erlang` to `/some/other/dir` back and forth)
4. I have the EXACT same versions of code in `/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib` and `/some/other/dir/lib`
5. I have filled out `.app` files for all my apps so the `.beam` files are present in both `/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/` and `/some/other/dir/lib/`
6. Erlang sees the code and loads it as far as `code:all_loaded()`/`code:get_path()` is concerned.
7. There are no clashes from `code:clash()`

And now I'm out of ideas. Any pointers? :)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion? Use [rebar](https://bitbucket.org/basho/rebar/wiki/Home).

Anyway, does your [.rel file](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/release_structure.html) contain those undefined applications?

Comment: Are the .beam files where they are supposed to be? In the path?